# How to change file icons in QFileSystemModel

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I have a code:

```cpp
QExplorer::QExplorer(QWidget *parent)
{
    QString sPath = "D:/";
    dirmodel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    dirmodel->setRootPath(sPath);
    treeView = new QTreeView(this);
    treeView->setModel(dirmodel);
    treeView->setRootIndex(dirmodel->index(sPath));
}
```

Now my icons looks like this:

[image]

But I want them to look like this:

[image]

How can I change file's and folder's icons?

Comment: Have a look at [`QFileSystemModel::setIconProvider `](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfilesystemmodel.html#setIconProvider).